# jQuery+Check if a array contains only IP adresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

I have an array like this (output from console.log):

```
["122.42.123.1", "122.42.123.1", "122.42.123.1", "awdawd", "awdawd"]
```

How could I check if it contains only IP addresses and if so `return true`? And in case it doesnt (like in the example above) `return false`?

I have tried various functions I found here and on Google ([like this one](http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2009/06/javascript-ip-address-validation.html)) and used them in a each loop, but that doesnt work:

```
//Get ip list from a textarea (each row = 1 ip)
var content = $("#banUList").val();
var ips = content.split("\n");
console.log(ips);

$(ips).each(function(){

    if(checkFunction($(this)) == false){
        //Wrong
    }else{
        //correct
    }

});
```

If possible I would like to **avoid** this loop at all, and have a function that checks the whole array for any `var` that is not an IP. No matter how many `vars` there are.

Comment: You can't avoid the `for` loop but you can stop it when it find a wrong IP with `break`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will do as you wish:

```
function ipOnly(arr) {
    for(var i=0,l=arr.length;i<l;i++)
        if(!/^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$/.test(arr[i])) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DWQzm/

Comment: No, it's not, since it doesn't avoid the for loop :)

Comment: Exactly my thought. Only suggestion so far without a loop is mine.

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood the OP. He doesn't mind a loop as long as he doesn't have to do the loop every time he need to do the check - he just wanted a utility function to do it for him :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidIp(value){
    // The code you got from google
    return true/false;
}

var valids = [];

$.each(ips, function(){
  if (isValidIp(this))  
      valids.push(this);
});
```

Or with the jQuery `grep` util:

```
var valids = $.grep(ips, function(element){
                 return isValidIp(element);
             });
```

---

If you just want to get true\false when all the address are valid\invalid:

```
var areAllValid = $.grep(ips, function(element){
                        return !isValidIp(element);
                     }).length === 0;
```

Comment: The question was how to check if all entries are ips, not to extract all valid ip addresses.

Comment: Good point, this `grep` function, but won't `areAllValid` be true if at least one element is an ip address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to validate the IP address:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

CHALLENGE: someone more experienced with regex than myself can probably write a multi-line aware regex that can validate the entire textarea in one sweep without using any looping.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply impossible to check *all* entries of a list without using a loop. To complete your source code:

```
function arrayConsistsOfIPAddresses(ips) {
   var result = true;
   $(ips).each(function() {
     result &= isIPAddress($(this));
   }
   return result;
}
```

You can use the regex posted by jbabey to implement the function `isIPAddress`:

```
function isValidIPAddress(value) {
    var ipRegex = /b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/b
    return value.match(ipRegex); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this version which does NOT use a loop
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Tqz9M/)

```
// regex from http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/
var re = /((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})/g; 

function isArrIpOnly(arr) {
  return arr.toString().match(re).length==arr.length;
}


var arr = ["122.42.123.1", "122.42.123.1", "122.42.123.1", "awdawd", "awdawd"];   

alert(isArrIpOnly(arr));
```